# ListFragment内でDLした画像（png）の保存方法を教えてください。

Tags: android, android-fragments

ListFragment内でDLした画像（png）の保存方法を教えてください。

お世話になっております。
　ListFragment内でサーバーに置いている画像を取り込み、アプリの内部ストレージに保存したいのですが、うまく行っておりません。
　アドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

詳細：
　jsonデータを習得、その中の画像アドレスを取り出すまでは完了しております。
　listViewに表示するようにしたいため、ListFragment内で処理したくopenFileOutputで一度、アプリ内で保存し必要になった時に呼び出したいのですがうまく行っておりません。
　openFileOutputがActivityで呼び出されるまでは理解したのですが、ListFragmentでどのようにすれば良いかがわからず困っております。
　implementを利用するのでしょうか？
　アドバイスを頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getActivity()`でAttachされているActivityインスタンスが取得できます。

Comment: fkm様
　前回の質問から引き続き、アドバイスを頂きありがとうございます。
　無事、解決いたしました。